# Bottom Sheet перекрывается другими элементами

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bottom-sheet

Открытый `BottomSheetBehavior` перекрывается `RecyclerView` и `BottomNavigation` (1-я картинка). При этом, если layout с BottomSheet переместить после FrameLayout,`<include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet_main" />` то только панель навигации перекрывает (2-я картинка). Как решить проблему?

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet_main" />


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ToolBar_Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Картинка 1]
[image: Картинка 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил это путем переставления `layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet_main" />` после `FrameLayout`. А так же в коде `MainActivity` добавил анимацию для `BottomNavigation`. Теперь при появлении `BottomSheet` панель навигации уходит вниз в зависимости от положении `BottomSheet`

```
 bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            bottom_navigation.animate().y((coordinatorlayout.height-bottom_navigation.height+bottom_navigation.height*slideOffset).toFloat()).setDuration(0).start()
        }

        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        }
    })
```